# Weird behavior with session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, session, heroku, cookies

I have a Rails application hosted on Heroku and I am preparing to deploy another application that will use the same session cookie. Let's assume that main application is hosted at `app.mycompany.com` and the new application will be hosted at `reports.mycompany.com`. I've setup session cookies in both apps with cookie domain `.mycompany.com` and everything works ok. I've modified `/etc/hosts` to test those settings on my local machine.

Since everything worked fine on my local machine I wanted to test it on our staging environment, which is hosted at `mycompany-staging.herokuapp.com`. For this app I've set cookie domain to `.herokuapp.com`. And now it does not work. It is not possible to login. From inspector it looks like correct `Set-Cookie` header is sent from the server, but the browser never send this cookie back on request.

The same thing happens on my local machine when pointing `mycompany-staging.herokuapp.com` to `127.0.0.1`. This happens only when I use `herokuapp.com`. Everything else works fine or at least couple of different domains work fine, including `herokuapp2.com`.

I am really confused. It looks like there is some cache issue, but I don't know where exactly. I am testing this mostly on Chrome with incognito mode, but I also tried Safari with the same problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or maybe I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `herokuapp.com` is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/). Cookie with domain `*.herokuapp.com` cannot be set any more. Refer to [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com) in devcenter.heroku.com:

> herokuapp.com is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List. This list is used in recent versions of several browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome and Opera, to limit how broadly a cookie may be scoped. In other words, in browsers that support the functionality, applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting cookies for *.herokuapp.com. Note that *.herokuapp.com cookies can currently be set in Internet Explorer, but this behavior should not be relied upon and may change in the future.